# Mobile Public Google Calendar in WebView

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, uiwebview, google-calendar-api

Is is possible to display the mobile version of a Google public calendar in an iPhone app without having to sign into the account? I'm looking to display the mobile site in an UIWebView on iOS 5.

Thanks in advance.